# Issue in reading JSON file in python

Tags: python, json

```
>>> import json
>>> d2 = json.loads(open("t.json").read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 319, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 336, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self._scanner.iterscan(s, **kw).next()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/scanner.py", line 55, in iterscan
    rval, next_pos = action(m, context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 185, in JSONObject
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting object", s, end))
ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 11 (char 11)
[ RHEL - ~/testing ]$ cat t.json
{"us": u"OFF", "val": u"5"}
```

Here is what I have in my JSON file and when I try to read it using `open` and `json.load` and json.loads it fails.

After using json.load

```
>>> import json
>>> d2 = json.load(open("t.json"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 267, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 319, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 336, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self._scanner.iterscan(s, **kw).next()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/scanner.py", line 55, in iterscan
    rval, next_pos = action(m, context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 185, in JSONObject
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting object", s, end))
ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 11 (char 11)
>>>
```

Comment: you have the answer in your own question: `TypeError: expected string or buffer`. try to read error message first.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr i have updated the output for json.load , sorry for missing it earlier

Comment: You don't have valid JSON data; remove the `u` prefixes.

Comment: this is what i have got as return value from api call , anyway to parse it

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong function. Use `json.load()` (no `s`!) to load data from an open file object:

```
d2 = json.load(open("t.json"))
```

The `json.loads()` function expects you to pass in a *string*, not a file object. You'd have to read your file in that case, returning the read data:

```
d2 = json.loads(open("t.json").read())
```

Next, you have invalid JSON in that file:

```
{"us": u"OFF", "val": u"5"}
#      ^              ^
```

JSON is not Python; those `u` prefixes are not supported nor needed. You'll need to remove those from the file before it'll load.

If you have an API producing that format, it is not giving you JSON. It could be that it is producing a (strange form of) Python syntax instead; Python itself would produce `{'us': u'OFF', 'val': u'5'}` (single quotes). You can have Python interpret that as Python literals with [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

with open('t.json') as fileobj:
    d2 = ast.literal_eval(fileobj.read())
```

but it could be that the format is broken in other ways we cannot determine from a single isolated sample. It could be using `true` and `false` for boolean values, like in JSON, for example.

Better to have the *API* fixed rather that try and work around this broken-ness.

Comment: i have updated the output for json.load , sorry for missing it earlier

Comment: You don't have valid JSON in your file, however.

Comment: this is what i have got as return value from api call , anyway to parse it

Comment: @mkp: any way to fix the API instead? You can try and interpret it as Python literals instead: `import ast` then `d2 = ast.literal_eval(open('t.json').read())` but that's slower and may break if there are nulls or booleans.

Comment: will it work if the data have much  more than simple two  element , like having multiple layered dict type format of data

Comment: @mkp: `ast.literal_eval()` will work with valid Python syntax, however deeply nested.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `json.loads` method. More documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads). This method is used for string arguments only. Luckily, there is a similarly named `json.load` method documented here. This one can be used directly on a file object.

```
d2 = json.load(open("t.json"))
```

Comment: i have updated the output for json.load , sorry for missing it earlier

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the JSON is not valid.

It looks like it is a python dictionnary. `u'string'` is a python 2 unicode string.

If you remove the `u` from your strings, it works fine.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.load(open('i.json'))
{u'val': u'5', u'us': u'OFF'}
```

Here is the json file:

```
$ cat i.json
{"us": "OFF", "val": "5"}
```

Comment: this is what i have got as return value from api call , anyway to parse it